# How to change image source when view model property changes

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

I'm building a WP8 application with MVVM Light and I encountered a silly problem I can't find and easy solution for.

In the XAML page I have the following:

```
        <Button Command="{Binding PlayCommand}" >
            <Image Source="Images/play.png"/>
        </Button>
```

When PlayCommand is executed, I change the value of *IsPlaying* property in the ViewModel to true. 
Now, I would want the XAML page to react to the change of *IsPlaying* and change the source of the Image to "Images/pause.png". In WPF I could do it with DataTriggers (also not convenient), but it doesn't seem to work in WP8. Of cource I could just bind the Image Source to the ViewModel like this, but that beats the entire purpose of MVVM.

```
    <Button Command="{Binding PlayCommand}" >
        <Image Source="{Binding PlayButtonImage}"/>
    </Button>
```

I know that there are complex solutions (for example, attached properties, behaviors, etc...), but I figure that there must be a simple one...

Comment: You can make a property in your ViewModel like `Uri PlayButtonImage` and there will be nothing wrong with MVVM

Comment: I just use 2 images and bind to the image visibility property with a bool to visibility converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the Image property in your ViewModel.

Comment: I guess you are right... This is why it is called a ViewModel and not a Model. Thanks.

Comment: years later... I'm afraid I have to disagree, Image/ImageSource class is part of view and therefore does not belong in the viewmodel. An image URI accesses also the view (resources) but in most cases it is used instead. IMHO a good way to separate view and viewmodel would be to use a key and a key-to-image converter.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a converter class like this one?

```
public class BoolToIconConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is bool)
        {
            bool isPlaying = (bool)value;
            if (isPlaying)
                return "Images/pause.png";
            else 
                return "Images/play.png"
        } 
        return "Images/play.png";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Used like this

```
<Button Command="{Binding PlayCommand}" >
    <Image Source="{Binding IsPlaying, Converter={StaticResource BoolToIconConverter}}"/>
</Button>
```

Although I don't think a property in MVVM would break your MVVM pattern, and may even give you better performance than using value converters.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I knew I could write a converter and that's exactly the stuff I wanted to avoid. Your comment about not breaking the MVVM pattern is probably right. I just was being way too righteous with by approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a BitmapImage in the Image using the Source property as such:

```
<Button Command="{Binding PlayCommand}" >
    <Image>
        <Image.Source>
            <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImageUri}"/>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
</Button>
```

You can then bind ImageUri to a notification property on your ViewModel of type Uri.